# RXJava Range gave me error of Type inference failed

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

While reading a book on RXJAVA, I am getting this error:

> Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is
>   Observable! but Observable was expected

From this simple snippet:

```
@Test
    fun deferable() {
       val source= Observable.range(1, 5)
                source.subscribe { s -> System.out.println("RECEIVED: $s "}
    }
```

I do not get I am  why when I run the test I get this strange message. During my daily activities I manage this kind of error changing the return of the variable/property (the expression type)
as `val source :Observable<Int>`

but does not work, also I tried to do something as `map{it.toString()}`
but without success, how can I achieve to make the "test" pass? I know is not a real test I am using it only to learn RXJAVA, so there are no assertions, what I expect is to see this output:

```
RECEIVED:5
RECEIVED:6
RECEIVED:7
RECEIVED:8
RECEIVED:9
RECEIVED:10
RECEIVED:11
RECEIVED:12
RECEIVED:13
RECEIVED:14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Observable! but Observable was expected

If you have such kind of compiler error, that means you are trying to pass nullable value instead of nonNull. You see the screamer: `Observable!` sign? This is the matter.

PS. test is green on my computer. Output is next:

```
RECEIVED: 1 
RECEIVED: 2 
RECEIVED: 3 
RECEIVED: 4 
RECEIVED: 5
```

Comment: Thank you, is working on my office pc as well this is strange, this evening I will try to make it nullable